# What is the meaning of dynamic type

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

```
dynamic a = 4;
```

dynamic is a type only in compilation time. Then **a** is a dynamic in compilation time, but in excecution time it is not. What happened when I say

```
a = "pp";
```

The type of **a** change in excecution (very odd), or it create a new variable a with string type.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> dynamic a = 4;
>
> What happened when I say
>
> a = "pp";

The string value `"pp"` is assigned to the variable `a`.

> The type of `a` change in excecution (very odd)

True (technically the *type* of what `a` *references* changes at runtime), but it's not odd - it works the same way if you use 'object':

```
object a = 4;
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name);  // Int32
a = "pp";
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name);  // string
```

The *variable* `a` can hold *any* type, what `a` actually *references* can change at runtime.

`dynamic` works very much like `object` in the sense that it can reference an object of any type.  The difference is that *operations* on `dynamic` variables are not checked at compile-time; they are deferred and bound at run-time.  So this is perfectly legal:

```
dynamic a = 4;
a = a + 1;
a = "pp";
Console.WriteLine(a.Substring(1,1));
```

You can't do that with `object` without casting since `object` does not define a `+` operator or a `Substring` method.